# BlueOcean connect with SSH key

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have an ssh key setup for the bitbucket team.

But the Blue Ocean UI only gives me the option for username and password which means I cant use it to create any pipelines:

[image]

I have to use the old UI for now, unless there is a way to do this in BlueOcean?

Comment: I guess this should have just been a feature request,  hopefully someone can update this when they add it. From what I understand this is more a limitation of bitbucket than jenkins? Maybe jenkins is making rest calls to bb which doesnt support an ssh key? Maybe to use bb cloud youll have to provide user creds for bb setup and then also provide ssh key for git- hope we get support soon.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose `Git` and then paste your `SSH URL`, 
you will see the `SSH Key` you need to add to `BitBucket`

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1coy1.png)